# How do I use a variable to call a class?

Tags: python

Code:

```
class Mega:
    def __init__(self, name, types, moves):
        self.name = name
        self.types = types
        self.moves = moves
  
ropher=Mega('Ropher', 'Sound', ['Screech', 'Coil'])
mijek=Mega('Mijek', 'Light', ['Solar Beam', 'Healing Sunlight'])

input=input('What mega? ').lower
print(f"your mega is {input.name}, a {input.types} type")
```

I want to use the user input to decide which Mega to call, but I can't find a way to go about it. The idea is to get it to print Ropher's name and type if the input is 'ropher', and Mijek's name if the input is 'mijek'. Can someone help?

Comment: You should use `dict` as data container there instead of variables. Accessing variables by string name in runtime is a *hack* which shouldn't be used for that purpose.

Comment: You do not "call" a class; you *instantiate* it. But what you are asking about is not that; you are trying to use a *string* input by the user in order to *choose* an existing object in your program. That has nothing to do with the class in question.

Comment: Why does eval exists in  every language if it is so dangerous? In python you got exec too.

Comment: @VisheshMangla, because there're rare cases where using `eval()` can be reasonable solution, but you should know what are you doing and how to minimize risks.

Comment: @VisheshMangla dynamic code execution is only dangerous with untrusted input. Usually, though, the problem is that someone is going about organizing their code in completely the wrong way, instead of thing about *data structure* they are thinking about everything in terms of "variables'. Variables are for writing source code, in almost every case when someone asks a question like this, the OP should be using *some sort of container*  like a list or a dict, instead of just dynamically creating variables in the global scope which is very brittle and hard to reason about.

Comment: thanks for the explanation @juanpa.arrivillaga .  I m too switching to better methods now than eval.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is better to use a dictionary instead of separate variables.  You then use a dictionary lookup to find the ones that you want.

```
class Mega:
    def __init__(self, name, types, moves):
        self.name = name
        self.types = types
        self.moves = moves

megas = {'ropher': Mega('Ropher', 'Sound', ['Screech', 'Coil']),
         'mijik': Mega('Mijek', 'Light', ['Solar Beam', 'Healing Sunlight'])}

key = input('What mega? ').lower()
print(f"your mega is {megas[key].name}, a {megas[key].types} type")
```

You should also not call your variable `input` because you override the builtin function.  In the above, I have renamed it as `key`.

Note that if the key that you try to look up does not exist in the dictionary, then your program will stop with a `KeyError`.  If you want to prevent this, you can first use `in` to check whether the input exists as one of the keys in the dictionary:

```
if key in megas:
    print(f"your mega is {megas[key].name}, a {megas[key].types} type")
else:
    print("not a valid mega")
```

or you can catch the `KeyError`:

```
try:
    print(f"your mega is {megas[key].name}, a {megas[key].types} type")
except KeyError:
    print("not a valid mega")
```

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple objects that you want to find by a common feature. In this case the lower-cased name. You can use a `dict` to index your objects by name and then find them easily later.

```
class Mega:
    def __init__(self, name, types, moves):
        self.name = name
        self.types = types
        self.moves = moves
  
mega_index = {}
ropher=Mega('Ropher', 'Sound', ['Screech', 'Coil'])
mega_index[ropher.name.lower()] = ropher
mijek=Mega('Mijek', 'Light', ['Solar Beam', 'Healing Sunlight'])
mega_index[mijek.name.lower()] = mijek

my_input=input('What mega? ').lower()
try:
    my_mega = mega_index[my_input]
    print(f"your mega is {my_mega.name}, a {my_mega.types} type")
except KeyError:
    print("No such mega")
```

This is just the tip of the iceberg. You really didn't need those ropher and mijek variables at all. They are in the dictionary and now can be acted on dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a dictionary:

```
megas = {
    'ropher': Mega('Ropher', 'Sound', ['Screech', 'Coil']),
    'mijek': Mega('Mijek', 'Light', ['Solar Beam', 'Healing Sunlight']),
}

input=megas[input('What mega? ').lower()]
print(f"your mega is {input.name}, a {input.types} type")
```